# Getting 405 method not allowed with Twilio SMS statusCallbackUrl

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am sending an SMS using twilio in php laravel. The code is mentioned below-

```
$twilioClient->messages->create(
       $mobile_phone,
       [
          'from' => config('twilio.twilio_sms_sender'),
          'body' => $message,
          'statusCallback' => url("/sms_mobile_validation/{$user->id}")
       ]
      );
```

In my web.php, route is defined as-

```
Route::post('/sms_mobile_validation/{userId}', 'Webhook\SMSWebhookController@mobileValidation');
```

Still I am getting 405 "Request to StatusCallback URL was not successful." every time I send SMS. Although the request in twilio debugger shows it's a Post request.

[image]

Need help with figuring out if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Take Twilio out of the equation. When you use a tool like Postman to POST to your webhook, do you get the same error?

Comment: hi @Alan - I get status 200 ok when I send a post call on postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lavravel by default all the post request are validating through `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware. So add your route inside   `protected $except = [..]` .